# Is there anyway to switch between source code and binary when using pre-compiling in Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, binary, cocoapods, reverse-engineering

I have a huge Xcode project, using [CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/plugins/pre-compiling-dependencies.html) with more than 150 dependencies. The indexing time and building time without Xcode building cache is a nightmare, Xcode is less responsive. All of these causes prevents us from effective development. So we are going to use [Pre-compiling](https://guides.cocoapods.org/plugins/pre-compiling-dependencies.html) in our project.

What this CocoaPods plugin mainly does are:

1. download source code to `Pods/_prebuild/xxx` folder
2. Build static frameworks in a temperate folder `Pods/build`  folder
3. Generate static frameworks and finally store them in `Pods/_prebuild/generatedFrameworks` folder
4. After building completed, delete the source code in the `Pods/_prebuild/xxx`, and generate the `xxx` folder in the `Pods`folder, which contains a symbolic link to the `static framework` in `Pods/_prebuild/generatedFrameworks` folder.  Besides, you can preserve the source code in the `Pods/_prebuild/` folder, if you use  `keep_source_code_for_prebuilt_frameworks` in the `Podfile`.

But, once the dependencies are converted into binary files. It is very difficult for developers to debug when development.

1. **A naive solution** is to use  `pod "ExpectoPatronum", :binary => true | false` and do `pod install` again.
   `cocoapods-binary` provides this optional to determine if this pod should be source code or should be converted into binary.
2. It seems this plugin is from a Chinese unicorn, [Mei Tuan](https://tech.meituan.com/2019/08/08/the-things-behind-the-ios-project-zsource-command.html). And, instead of using the solution 1 to switch between source code and binary, they use a more tricky way to convert the binary into source code.

Currently, I am trying to find more solutions to switch between source code and binary when using pre-compiling in CocoaPods . Would you like to shed some light on it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems and developed my own utility  [**Rugby**](https://github.com/swiftyfinch/Rugby).
In the current version, `Rugby` can cache all remote pods dependencies and remove their targets from the `Pods` project.

Also, `Rugby` doesn't change `Podfile`. You can use `pod install && rugby` for working with cache or just `pod install` for working with sources.